# How to sort strings (containing a names and age) first alphabetically and then by age within name groups

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, selection

My asignment: Take the initial list, put it in a text file named "Names_ages.txt" and use **selection sort** (no other sort) to alphabetically sort it. but also sort repeating names by age. Age goes from youngest to oldest.

**Initial list (to be sorted):**

Jones 14

Abrams 15

Smith 19

Jones 9

Alexander 22

Smith 20

Smith 17

Tippurt 42

Jones 2

Herkamn 12

Jones 11

**Finished list (after a correct sort):**

Abrams 15

Alexander 22

Herkman 12

Jones 2

Jones 9

Jones 11

Jones 14

Smith 17

Smith 19

Smith 20

Tippurt 42

My scanner class to make the text file an array (no errors, works fine)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ScannerClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ScannerClass.textFile();
    }
    public static void textFile()
    {
        String line;
        String[] names = new String[11];

        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Names_ages.txt")))
        {
            line = reader.readLine();

            for(int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
            {
                names[i] = line;
                //System.out.println(names[i]);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        SortClass.selectionSort(names);
    }
}
```

My selection sort class (I post what it prints out):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SortClass
{
    public static void selectionSort(String names[])
    {
        for(int i=0; i<names.length-1; ++i){
            int minIndex = i;
            for(int j=i+1; j<names.length; ++j)
            {
                if(names[j].compareTo(names[minIndex])<0)
                {
                    int indexChar1 = names[j].indexOf(' ');
                    int indexChar2 = names[minIndex].indexOf(' ');
                    String name1 = names[j].substring(0, indexChar1);
                    String name2 = names[minIndex].substring(0, indexChar2);
                    if(name1.equals(name2))
                    {
                        String number1 = names[j].substring(indexChar1+1); //names[j]
                        String number2 = names[minIndex].substring(indexChar2+1); //names[minIndex]
                        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1); //names[j]
                        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2); //names[minIndex]
                        if(num1>num2)
                            continue;
                        if(num1<num2)
                            minIndex = j;
                    }
                    else
                        minIndex = j;

                }
            }
            String temp = names[i];
            names[i] = names[minIndex]; 
            names[minIndex] = temp;
        }
        printNames(names);
    }

    public static void printNames(String names[])
    {
        for(int l=0; l<11; l++)
        {
            System.out.println(names[l]);
        }
    }
}
```

**What my sort prints out:**

Abrams 15

Alexander 22

Herkamn 12

Jones 2

*Jones 11* (These two need to be switched)

*Jones 9*

Jones 14

Smith 17

Smith 19

Smith 20

Tippurt 42

I am not sure how to fix the jones mess up, I am guessing that it **is** putting them in order, but rather in pairs than just all four. How would I fix it so that the Jones are in sequential order in terms of age like the finished list above?

Answer (score 2):

Here is your `SortClass` after a minor modification. Test it and let me know

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SortClass
{
    public static void selectionSort(String names[])
    {
        for(int i=0; i<names.length-1; ++i){
            int minIndex = i;
            for(int j=i+1; j<names.length; ++j)
            {
                int indexChar1 = names[j].indexOf(' ');
                int indexChar2 = names[minIndex].indexOf(' ');
                String name1 = names[j].substring(0, indexChar1);
                String name2 = names[minIndex].substring(0, indexChar2);

                if(name1.compareTo(name2)<0)
                {
                    minIndex = j;
                } else if(name1.compareTo(name2) == 0){

                        String number1 = names[j].substring(indexChar1+1); //names[j]
                        String number2 = names[minIndex].substring(indexChar2+1); //names[minIndex]
                        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1); //names[j]
                        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2); //names[minIndex]
                        if(num1>num2)
                            continue;
                        if(num1<num2)
                            minIndex = j;

                }
            }
            String temp = names[i];
            names[i] = names[minIndex]; 
            names[minIndex] = temp;
        }
        printNames(names);
    }

    public static void printNames(String names[])
    {
        for(int l=0; l<11; l++)
        {
            System.out.println(names[l]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @HardlyTheJavaLegend - There was a mistake in your logic, specifically in the line `if(names[j].compareTo(names[minIndex])<0)`. You can not compare the entire lines. The logic should be - Compare the names (after splitting), if `names[j]` (after splitting) is lexicographically less than `names[minIndex]` (after splitting) then you update the `minindex`, **without** comparing the numbers. if names are equal **ONLY THEN** you compare the ages